# NodeJS: libxmljs could not build

Tags: node.js

This library is a hell. I could not consistently install it on an arbitrary Unix platform. I was able to get to OSX and alpine linux but now trying to install it for the same project on Cent OS and it is failing. It was failing the same way on other platforms but after numerous tries it got installed. Here I could not find a solution.

```
 npm --unsafe-perm install libxmljs
```

Here is the output

```
node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.4/node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.4/node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.4/node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for libxmljs@0.18.4 and node@6.9.5 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs/releases/download/v0.18.4/node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz 
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.9.5/node-v6.9.5-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.9.5/node-v6.9.5-headers.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:569:26)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.27-boot2docker
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--loglevel=http" "--module=/opt/tc_base/Proj-Node/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Release/xmljs.node" "--module_name=xmljs" "--module_path=/opt/tc_base/Proj-Node/node_modules/libxmljs/build/Release"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/tc_base/Proj-Node/node_modules/libxmljs
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.18.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.18.4 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

Here it should be building it from source. And on some other platforms it is reluctantly doing it. But not on CentOS.

I tried different versions of Node. 6.9.5 gave me a best luck of getting it installed on other platforms. But on CentOS it seems to could not get installed no matter what.

Declaimer: It is a DOCKER version of CentOS. However should not really matter because after a long struggle it kinda got installed on alpine

I could not be the one struggling here because this thing should fail everywhere. Nothing special on the environment I have.

PS: Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install curl wget bash bash-completion sudo vim net-tools openssh redis python make libtool-ltdl java gcc-c++ libxslt-devel
RUN yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'

RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN yum -y install nodejs
RUN npm install -g n
RUN n 6.9.5
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN npm --unsafe-perm  install libxmljs
```

Comment: Do you have `libxslt-devel` installed in your docker container?

Comment: I added it but it did not help. Bellow is the full Docker file

Comment: That dockerfile succeeds for me:
```
$ docker build -t test .; echo $?
....
0
```

Comment: Yep, it was VirtualBox issue. Version of 5.1.8 has some networking issue that leads to signed archives to be corrupted after delivery. So node source code was downloaded such a way that signature did not match.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted a day trying to build a container just to figure out that there is a bug in virtual box that makes node lib archives occasionally (99% of the time) to arrive with a corrupted SSH signatures

every time signature has to be validated and it is corrupted build will fail

Here is more [details](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1040).

Comment: 5.1.8 is the version of VirtualBox that has this issue